# odoo-13 create treeview inside treeview

Tags: xml, treeview, odoo-13

in odoo 10 its possible to create treeview inside treeview using:

```
  <field name="view_type">tree</field>
```

for examble:

```
<record id="res_partner_action_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
  <field name="name">Partners</field>
  <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
  <field name="view_type">tree</field>
  <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
  <field name="help" type="html">
    <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
    </p>
    <p>
    </p>
  </field>
</record>
```

and its will make view something like this:

[check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBE1W.png)

but this feature is dropped in odoo-13, is there are an alternative way to make similar view?

i tried to remove:

```
  <field name="view_type">tree</field>
```

and only use:

```
  <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
```

and it will only get a list without chlid:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXlSc.png)